# How to Diagnose Unresponsiveness on a Next.js Site Deployed on Vercel?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I am experiencing a challenging issue with a Next.js website hosted on Vercel, which has been reported by users but is not reproducible on our end. The website (URL: [https://kw.boshamlan.com/)](https://kw.boshamlan.com/) becomes unresponsive for some users that they can’t interact with the page, including clicking buttons.

- **Issue Description**: Users are unable to interact with the site; pages appear frozen. This issue has been reported by multiple users using both Android and iOS mobile devices in Kuwait and other countries such as UAE and Qatar.
- **Frequency**: The issue is intermittent and not reproducible by our development team.
- **User Environment**: Chrome browser on Android, Safari browser on iOS, as per user reports. Users who reported have been using the website for long time with no issues at all in the past.
- **Recent Changes**: Our website was originally a Laravel app until last year. We revamped it using Next.js and Vercel on 01 January 2024. and the issue started after switching to Next.js.
- **Attachments for Reference**:

  - [Video of the Issue](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dJ2FPfji58rTZVRPkRaHIwHUn93xngOt/view?usp=sharing)
  - [Image Snapshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V8V5vearxUpRo-szegGeU6t7wEuslWWN/view)

I am looking for insights or suggestions on the following:

- Possible causes of such intermittent unresponsiveness in a Next.js application, especially in a mobile environment.
- Recommended tools or methods for diagnosing issues that are not reproducible in a development setting.
- Any similar experiences or solutions that the community might have encountered.

Your expertise and suggestions would be immensely valuable in helping us resolve this issue. Thank you in advance for your help!

We used Sentry for error logging but haven't received any useful logs related to this issue. Additionally, we tested the site on various real devices and used device simulators on lambdatest.com. Despite these efforts, we couldn't replicate the issue or identify its cause.